# Size of popup window with window.open inconsistent and resize inner width/height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to open a popup window with the exact size I provide.

I'm using

```
window.open(url,'newwindow','resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top)
```

For my example I used:

```
width='400px'
height='300px'
top=left='300px'
```

In Chrome it works fine and I get a new window with inner size of 400x300px.

In IE (v11) I get a window with 404x304px.

In FF (v31) I get a window with 398x299px.

But I need it to be exactly 400x300px like in Chrome or I get big problems with my window resize event listener.

I'm going nuts here, so am I doing something wrong here? Does anyone know how to solve this, or is it a known issue?

I am just using plain HTML/JavaScript for this project.

Edit:

I just came up with a little workaround.
I just add this inside the HEAD tag of my popup html:

```
<script>
    window.innerResizeTo = function(targetWidth, targetHeight) {
        if(window.innerWidth || window.innerHeight) {
            var innerWidth = window.innerWidth,
            innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else {
            var innerWidth = window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth,
            innerHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight;
        }

        if (innerWidth != targetWidth && innerHeight != targetHeight) {
            if(window.outerWidth || window.outerHeight) {
                var outerWidth = window.outerWidth,
                outerHeight = window.outerHeight,
                fixedwidth = targetWidth + outerWidth - innerWidth,
                fixedheight = targetHeight + outerHeight - innerHeight;
            } else {
                window.resizeTo(300,300);

                var outerWidth = window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth,
                outerHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight,
                fixedwidth = targetWidth + 300 - outerWidth,
                fixedheight = targetHeight + 300 - outerHeight;
            }

            window.resizeTo(fixedwidth,fixedheight);
        }
    }

    window.innerResizeTo(400,300);

</script>
```

It's pretty ugly but it works (on win7 x64 with IE v11 FF v31 & Chrome v36).

I hope this can help someone else with the same or a similar problem.
Improvment ideas are very welcome btw.

Comment: Just wondering.. did you try adding 'px' to specify the size? Or browser is assuming that you r passing pixels?

Comment: Yes, just edited the question. The px was already in my vars and I just forget to add it here ;)

Comment: i guess there is no problem with the code may be the browser decorations are excluded in ie and taken in firefox

Comment: for testing I opened a html in the popup window with 2 divs first on black 400x300 with 1px padding (border-box so the 1px padding is included in the 400x300) and a gray one inside. In IE I have a White 4px border at bottom and right in FF The black border (1st div) is missing at bottom and right.